# Copy multiple rows and columns for non blank value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a set of data to a different format for export.

I want copy only rows with values.

Starting with Column D (see attached), I want to filter for non-blank values and copy across columns B, C, D, CellD2, CellD3 in five columns of a new sheet. Then repeat the same for all columns that have a value after column D.

The data set could have multiple columns (no fixed limit) and multiple rows (no fixed limit).

This is the data I am working on (Sheet name is "LJM Fert")
[image]

This is the final result I am trying to achieve (Sheet name is "Export")
[image]

The code I have written

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim Totalrows As Long
Dim Totalcolumns As Long
Dim rowloop As Long
Dim columnloop As Long
Dim rowcount As Long
Dim columncount As Long
Dim pastestart As Long

    Sheets("LJM Fert").Activate

    Totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Totalcolumns = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    rowcount = 4
    columncount = 4
    pastestart = 2
        
    For rowloop = rowcount To Totalrows
        
        For columnloop = columncount To Totalcolumns
        
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(rowcount, columncount).Value <> "" Then

                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowcount, 2).Copy
                Sheets("Export").Activate
                ActiveSheet.Cells(pastestart, 1).Paste
                Sheets("LJM Fert").Activate
        
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowcount, 3).Copy
                Sheets("Export").Activate
                ActiveSheet.Cells(pastestart, 2).Paste
                Sheets("LJM Fert").Activate
        
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowcount, columncount).Copy
                Sheets("Export").Activate
                ActiveSheet.Cells(pastestart, 3).Paste
                Sheets("LJM Fert").Activate
       
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, columncount).Copy
                Sheets("Export").Activate
                ActiveSheet.Cells(pastestart, 4).Paste
                Sheets("LJM Fert").Activate
        
                ActiveSheet.Cells(3, columncount).Copy
                Sheets("Export").Activate
                ActiveSheet.Cells(pastestart, 5).Paste
                Sheets("LJM Fert").Activate
        
            End If
        
            columncount = columncount + 1
            pastestart = pastestart + 1
        
        Next
    Next
                   
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
'Define Variables
Dim shtExport As Worksheet, shtFert As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell as Range

'Assign Variables
Set shtExport = Sheets("Export")
Set shtFert = Sheets("LJM Fert")

i = 1 'first line where to copy data in Sheet "Export"

For Each cell In shtFert.Range("D4:G20") 'Go through each cell in table

    If cell.Value <> 0 Then

        shtExport.Cells(i, 1) = shtFert.Cells(cell.Row, 2) 'Column A
        shtExport.Cells(i, 2) = shtFert.Cells(cell.Row, 3) 'Column B
        shtExport.Cells(i, 3) = shtFert.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column) 'Column C
        shtExport.Cells(i, 4) = shtFert.Cells(2, cell.Column) 'Column D
        shtExport.Cells(i, 5) = shtFert.Cells(3, cell.Column) 'Column E

    i = i + 1 'use next row in sheet Export

    End If

Next
```

What this basically do is go through each cell in the range D4:G20 of your sheet "LJM Fert", checks if this cell is different than 0, if it is: it will "copy" this cell in the Export sheet. And so on for each cell different than 0.

In any case, please make sure you don't use copy/paste, it's really slow compared to what I wrote above. Best is to set ranges, or cells, equal to each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You're awesome :)

Comment: @Jess You're welcome! Could you please mark the answer as accepted ? I'm new here, so it will help me as well !